# Delphi TDataSet in a runtime package

Tags: delphi, package

I am creating a runtime package which contains classes that my main application can use, but I'm having problems with the data access.
My main app contains a TDatabase which points to a BDE alias.  At runtime my package is dynamically loaded, and a method invoked in the package which creates a TQuery and opens it, populates an object with the returned data and then returns the object to the main app.  The TQuery uses the TDatabase in the main app to connect to the database.
All this works fine, but when I close the app I get an access violation: "Project C:...GUI.exe faulted with message 'access violation at 0x7c9102db: write of address 0x00040ffc'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue".
If my method creates the TQuery but doesn't open it then this error does not occur.  I have no idea why this happens!  When I close th app my TQuery is closed and freed ok, my package is unloaded ok, but after the form is destroyed the error occurs.
I'm using Delphi 5 BTW, I've tried to be brief so if I have missed out any helpful info let me know, any help gratefully received.

Thanks

p.s. I know that using Delphi 5 and BDE is archaic but I'm stuck with it for now!

Answer (score 1):

What if you don't free your TQuery? I mean, try not to free your TQuery object when application terminates.

Comment: Ok I've just tried that, but it makes no difference, the error still occurs

Comment: Is the TQuery owned by another component? Or created as `Qry := TQuery.Create(nil)`? If the former

Comment: It isn't owned by anything, I create it with nil owner as you have shown (because the class that it resides within is not derived from TComponent)

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me using dbExpress, the finalization section would fire *before* a datamodule destructor, when application was `Abort()`ed and that caused a lot of head ache.

So, my guess would be that

- BDE's connection driver (or some other resource) is finalizing before the destruction of something that uses it, therefore attempting to finalize the connection twice.

I say driver because those are usually only loaded/initialized on demand, thus it wouldn't fault if it wasn't used. So, maybe when your package is unloaded it finalizes the drivers.

Try this:

- load your package,
- use the TQuery contained in the package,
- unload your package,
- use another TQuery created in the main application,

and see if this works without raising exceptions. If it doesn't work then I guess I could be right, and we'll try to figure out how to make this work.

God bless!

Comment: I have just tried creating and using another tquery after unloading my package, but the query worked fine and the AV still occurred when closing the app.

Comment: I have found that if I connect my TQuery to a TDatabase within the package then the error does not occur, unless I also have a TDatabase in the app which gets opened.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a unit initialization/finalization order issue. Usually that is determined by the order of units in the uses lists, and what packages your package requires.

Best way to try to solve it is to debug Delphi with Delphi, **or your package with a .EXE**.
The last one is important, because older Delphi versions won't always find the symbols for your package if you start debugging with your EXE.

Steps

1. Start a Delphi that does not contain your package
2. Load your package in Delphi
3. Set the host of your package to be Delphi
4. Compile your package with full debug information, and enable the option 'debug DCU's'
5. Run your package (it should now load Delphi, then your package)
6. Terminate Delphi
7. Watch the call stack when the AV occurrs

You might want to set breakpoints to watch your initialization/finalization order (see [this post](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/delphi-great-post-by-malcolm-groves-about-debugging-initialization-and-finalization-sections/), the references and the comments for a discussion on that).

Then fiddle with your uses lists and package requirements sections.

--jeroen

Comment: While the initialization/finalization remark seems valid, the debugging Delphi with Delphi technique works while trying to find errors while in design-time, that happen in the IDE. Here he's talking about loading packages at runtime (like dlls), that is, while the application is running. It has nothing to do with debugging Delphi components.

Comment: I was under the impression that the packages had to do with Design time. The debugging technique works equally well when debugging packages at run-time.